Salesforce User Object do not update LastModifiedDate and SystemModStamp when LastLoginDate is updated
I just observed that if User.LastLoginDate changes every time user logs in. But the  LastModifiedDate and SystemModStamp fields remain unchanged when the User.LastLoginDate is updated. Salesforce's documentation do not address this behavior.
Below are is my data from today's logig
LastLoginDate - 8/30/2024 10:11 AM
LastModifiedDate - 8/15/2024 1:08 PM
SystemModstamp - 8/30/2024 12:33 AM

This sounds about right. You're not updating a field like name or username so you're not doing an edit. I think the last login date is less of a field and more of a reference.

This would seem to fall under the purview of Difference between SystemModStamp and LastModifiedDate in my opinion. That is, LastModifiedDate is updated when a user makes a change, and SystemModStamp is updated when the system makes a change.

Thanks @DanWooding. That's what I thought but Salesforce's documentation does not make this behavior clear. I am assuming same is true for User.LastViewedDate
